# Python logging: standard approach to log to a live object?

Tags: python, logging, vim

I'm a heavy Vim user and I intend to rewrite my python program entirely as an Vim extension, the 
idea is to have Vim act as an text-based UI for the program. Since Vim will have full access to every corner of the running program, I can control its operations on the fly through Vim self-defined key strokes and/or commands, and inspect live objects of the program (also its outputs) through Vim windows, not much need to be done through the transition.

Now my concern is the logging method. Since Vim and Python will become one, I don't need to log
to a seperate entity like a file or a socket, I only need to log to a live Python object, to say a list, and to view that list through a Vim window. Previouslly I had a top level StreamLogger logging to stdout, I've come up with a solution to seamlessly replace it:

```
import threading
import datetime

class ObjectLogger:
    mapping= {
        'critical': 5,
        'error':    4,
        'warning':  3,
        'info':     2,
        'debug':    1,
        'notset':   0,
    }

    def __init__(self):
        self.data= []   # logging output
        self._lock= threading.Lock()    
        self._level= 0

    # ----------------- methods for setting logging level -----------------
    def set_critical(self):
        self._level= ObjectLogger.mapping['critical']

    # ------------------------------ logging ------------------------------
    def debug(self, message):
        if self._level > ObjectLogger.mapping['debug']:
            return None
        self._lock.acquire()
        self.data.append(datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S') + ' >> ' + message)
        self._lock.release()

    # ---------------------- clear previous loggings ----------------------
    def clear(self):
        self._lock.acquire()
        del self.data[:]
        self._lock.release()
```

The question is, is there a better way to do this? Is there a standard approach to log to a live Python object? I've looked into MemoryHandler but it does not seem like what I need, thanks.

Comment: you should know that if you don't somehow persist the log messages, you will lose all those traces when you for example restart your application.  why not just write things in log file with python log module and control vim to reload the file or fill message in a window?

Comment: @Kent: You're right sir, but for debugging, you know, Its hard to know where to put the log lines until something already happens, so previously I was just using the logging system for its day-to-day output which most part you don't care about, despite knowing the program is still responding, just like when using shell I usually don't save its output. If something serious happens, like Python cause Vim to crush, I'll find way to log the key info into a file. For other important running info, like online transaction record, I use pickle module to save them as reusable Python object on the fly.

Comment: @Kent: Besides, I guess I'm somehow obsessed with the idea that Vim can be used as a UI, being able to inspect live Python object during run time also reduce the significance of the text logging system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [BufferingHandler](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#memoryhandler), which will allow you to use normal python logging facuilities, but instead of writing the log messages to disk, it'll just store them in a list, unformatted, for you to operate on as you please.

```
>>> import logging.handlers
>>> object_handler = logging.handlers.BufferingHandler(float('inf'))
>>> logging.root.handlers.append(object_handler)
>>> logging.root.level = logging.DEBUG
>>> something = object()
>>> object_handler.buffer
[]
>>> logging.info("something happened", something)
>>> object_handler.buffer
[<logging.LogRecord object at ...>]
>>> object_handler.buffer[-1].args[0] is something
True
```

Comment: Right! Seems object_handler.buffer is the key, guess I can do things like this:

    # Vim from another thread
    object_handler.acquire()
    # ... read out/modify object_handler.buffer in proper way ...
    object_handler.release()

now the question is to make the operations completelly thread-safe, maybe use only strings for 'something' would help, I'm looking into LogRecord attributes now, may need a little more work to sort it out, thanks for the useful reply ~

Comment: Well, you could use BufferingHandler as a baseclass or as inspiration for writing your own handler that is thread safe in the way you desire, perhaps using a `Queue.Queue` instead of a list

Comment: new findings, QueueHandler together with QueueListener may be exactly my solution, they're new since version 3.2, which is the version I'm using :)